# Testing if a certain number is within a list of ranges

Tags: python, list, range

How do I test how many times a certain number is outside my list of ranges?

Example:

```
value = 1
Ranges_array = [[0, 2], [2, 4], [0, 3]]
output = 1
```

So, the output generated will be 1 because there is only one range where the value of 1 does not lie within.

Answer (score 4):

Well, those aren't actually Ranges, but two-element lists. You could use manual comparison, as in the other answers, but in my answer I turn them into actual Range objects.

Since Python's `range(a,b)` constructor is inclusive at `a` (that is, `a` is inside the range) and exclusive at `b` (`b` is outside the range), you have to add 1 to one of the endpoints if you want them both to be inclusive or exclusive. I assumed you wanted inclusive, so added 1 to the high end point:

```
sum(1 for a,b in Ranges_array if value not in range(a,b+1))
```

Comment: May I suggest generator expression, instead of list comprehension? Btw. very nice!

Comment: Btw. it's "very nice", because this `in range` is O(1), as seen [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/rangeobject.c#L338).

Comment: @EcirHana only in Python 3, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sum` and a generator expression:

```
>>> sum(not a <= value <= b for a, b in ranges_array)
1
```

`a` and `b` are lower and upper range bounds, respectively. `a <= value <= b` is a [*chained comparison*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), equivalent to `a <= value and value <= b`. The final return value is the number of times the `not a <= value <= b` expression evaluated to `True`.

We can get a slightly longer but more readable solution if we apply De Morgan's laws:

```
>>> sum(value < a or value > b for a, b in ranges_array)
1
```

---

Technically, you *can* use `range` as shown in other answers, but they will be slower in Python 3 (due to the creation of the `range` object) and *much* slower in Python 2 (because Python 2's `range` creates an actual list, and containment checks on lists are *O(n)*):

```bash
$ python3.6 -m timeit -s "a, b, value = 0, 1000, 500" "a <= value <= b"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0343 usec per loop
$ python3.6 -m timeit -s "a, b, value = 0, 1000, 500" "value in range(a, b + 1)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.28 usec per loop
$ python2.7 -m timeit -s "a, b, value = 0, 1000, 500" "value in range(a, b + 1)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.97 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension should be enough.

```
output=len([k for k in Ranges_array if k[0]>value or k[1]<value])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `list comprehension` :

```
>>> sum([1 for x,y in ranges if not x<=value<=y])
=> 1

#OR

>>> len([1 for x,y in ranges if not x<=value<=y])
=> 1
```

Using `generators` *(recommended as it will be faster)* :

```
>>> sum(1 for x,y in ranges if not x<=value<=y)
=> 1
```

#driver value :

```
IN : ranges = [[0,2], [2,4], [0,3]]
```

Comment: Note: `x<value<y` does not include `x` and `y`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
value = 1
Ranges_array= [[0,2],
          [2,4],
          [0,3]]
output = 0
for r in Ranges_array:
    if value not in range(r[0], r[1]):
        output +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a parellel solution:

```
my_value = 1
Ranges_array = [[0,2],[2,4],[0,3]]
output = 1

count = 0
for listt in Ranges_array:
    if not my_value in range(listt[0],listt[-1]):
        count+= 1

print count
```